# How to multilookup from One Site List to another Site List in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lookup

I have a List defined in a SharePoint Site e.g. Countries list.

In another site, I have a List that needs to have a column with multilookup to the above Countries list. (So these 2 sites are separate sites)

How would that be possible to configure this in SharePoint 2010?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is possible but requires some programming or scripting, because cross site lookup field can't be configured using web UI.
PowerShell code should be following:

> $web1 = Get-SPWeb "http://site/web1"
>  $web2 = Get-SPWeb
>   "http://site/web2"
>  $list = $web1.Lists["My list"]
>   $lookupList = $web2.Lists["My lookup list"]
>   $list.Fields.AddLookup("MyCrosssiteLookup", $lookupList.ID, $web2.ID,
>   $false)
>  $lookupField =
>   list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(InternalName)
>   $lookupField.Title = "My cross site lookup"
>   $lookupField.Update()

Alternatively you can use LookupWithPicker field type, it has web UI control to configure cross-site lookpups: http://ilovesharepoint.codeplex.com/releases/view/44989.

Comment: thanks Ivan. the LookupWithPicker tool does seem to support cross-site lookups when those sites exist under the same site collection. What about when the sites are under separate site collections?

Comment: Data inside site collection is isolated by design, so there is now out-of-box method to query data from another site collection (standard lookup and lookup with picker does not allow that as well). So you have to develop your own code for that.

Comment: If you want data to be available across site collection you can use SharePoint Managed metadata service